# Adding flow to an existing project

Tags: flowtype

Is it viable to add [Flowtype](http://flowtype.org/) to an existing, large project?

I added `/* @flow weak */` to a single `.js` file, and then ran `flow check` and it's highlighting tons of function calls to globally defined libs because it has no idea what any of them are. So I updated my `.flowconfig` file to look like this:

```
[ignore]
node_modules/
bower_components/
typings/

[include]
twig/

[libs]
bower_components/timezone-js/src/date.js
bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js
bower_components/jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate.js
bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js
bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js
bower_components/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js
bower_components/jquery.expander/jquery.expander.js
bower_components/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.js
www/js/select2.js
bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
bower_components/lodash/lodash.js
bower_components/underscore.string/lib/underscore.string.js
bower_components/json2/json2.js
bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js
bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js
bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js
bower_components/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
bower_components/jquery.taps/jquery.taps.js
bower_components/file-saver.js/FileSaver.js
bower_components/react/react.js
bower_components/react/react-dom.js
bower_components/react/react-dom-server.js
node_modules/babel-core/external-helpers.js
node_modules/babel-core/browser-polyfill.js
... more libs ...

[options]
munge_underscores=true
```

And now it just runs out of memory when I run `flow check`.

So, what then? Is my project just too big to use flow?

Comment: IMO flow is not viable until [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/869) is resolved.

Answer (score 13):

Paths in `.flowconfig` are regular expressions over absolute paths. So, to ignore everything under `node_modules` and `bower_components` you would use something like this:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
.*/bower_components/.*
```

The `[libs]` section contains paths to Flow *[declarations](http://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html)* (interface files), which is where you define the types for the globals in your app. You could point this to a directory where you keep all your interface files:

```
[libs]
.*/lib/interfaces/.*
```

For example, for jQuery, you could have the following declaration:

```
declare module "jQuery" {
  declare function $(element: any): any;
}
```

Note that we've used the `any` type, which is effectively turning off type checking for this argument or return type.

See also the section on [third-party integrations](http://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html) in the docs.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct. I also want to add that as as Flow version 0.22, you probably don't need to ignore all of `node_modules`, as Flow no longer parses non-`@flow` files, which caused a number of issues in the past.

From 0.22 on, it's better to target specific problem files within `node_modules` instead. The default behavior for a found, but non-`@flow` module is `any`, which saves a lot of boilerplate like in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Martin's answer, because the `any` type syntax was a little tricky to track down, in many cases `declare function exports(args: any): any;` is a catch-all so that you don't have to declare every property in a module (e.g. `_.all`,`_.each` and so on for underscore). It doesn't work in all cases though.

Here's a snippet of a sample interface file I've used that semi-works:

```
declare module 'jquery' {
  declare function exports(args: any): any;
}

declare module 'underscore' {
  declare function exports(args: any): any;
}

// "declare function exports" doesn't seem to work in this case
declare module 'react' {
  declare var PropTypes: any;
  declare var Component: any;
  declare function createElement(args: any): any;
  // ...and so on
}
```

For a more detailed interface file example, you can see what [facebook/flow's interface files look like on github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/v0.22.0/lib).